# How to delete / exclude spinner items frame?

Tags: android, spinner, frame

I did custom look for spinner items. But after that I realized that there's still white frame (surrounding buttons). It's more visible on pic#2 where button images are 'shorter'. Do you guys know how to exclude white frames (not to show them)?

Theme used:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"    
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_select" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinnertext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </FrameLayout>
```

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/402/72449930.png/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can leave all buttons like: `android:layout_width="fill_parent"` with `android:orientation="vertical"` and `RelativeLayout` so the buttons will always be bigger/large and not depending on the Text in it.

Comment: well, I've changed my post above.Width doesn't depend on textview width.

Comment: You made the theme/buttons design? if so, try making them fill all the space provided.

Comment: via getDropDownView I create customView for spinner as shown above: (FrameLayout w/ textview). Green button is frameLayout background.

Comment: Im sorry i dont know about creating that... :x

Comment: trust me. In order to do so, I had to google so much.. :)
But now I can't solve this white frame issue..